# How to encode URL being passed to div.load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a URL rewrite and using

```
 $('#somediv').load(query, function (response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
        var msg = "Sorry there was an error: ";
        $("#somediv").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

But the div.laod() wont work when  my `query`  has character like '?','&' and '='.
As in when I pass parameters as shown beloew, div rendering wont happen .

```
query ="http://vmsbawcm001.ed.cps.something.com/content/pms/Snapshot.html?date=2011-09-30&email=something@gmail.com&view=external"
```

But this works!

```
 query ="http://vmsbawcm001.ed.cps.something.com/content/pms/Snapshot.html"
```

So How do I pass parameters in some encoded way? or any other solution for this is welcome, coz I am clueless..

After some more research, I have a doubt that it is only the `@` symbol which is creating the problem. Is it so? If yes, what is the possible solution fro that?

Thanks,
Adarsh

Comment: Oh not that was just a typo, Anyways I am not storing the entrire url string that way, I am getting it from Webconfig, also appending the parameters, I just put the whole thing to let know what exactly is being passed in the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter in `.load()` is for passing query data. Here's the reference: http://api.jquery.com/load/.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/EKHbQ/

HTML:

```html
<div id="somediv"></div>
```

Script:

```js
var uri = 'http://vmsbawcm001.ed.cps.something.com/content/pms/Snapshot.html',
    data = {date:"2011-09-30",email:"something@gmail.com",view:"external"};

$( '#somediv' ).load( uri, data, function ( response, status, xhr ) {

    if ( status == 'error' ) {

        var msg = 'Sorry there was an error: ';
        $( '#somediv' ).html( msg + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText );

    };

});
```

Comment: Ok , this does seem to work out, I Will be using something lik  data = {date:dateval,email:emailId,view:viewtype};     where dateval(type Date) emailId and viewType(type var). My question is I dont need to define date, email and view seperately right? I can directly use it inside data?

Comment: Yes. You can put variables or data directly in maps. Is that your question? {date: new Date(), email: emailvar, view: "viewtype"} will work, for example.